# I can't change the project and package name

Tags: android, project, renaming, package-name

We've tried all the instructions from other answers that we got from this site. We tried renaming our project on the res> values> string.xml, on refactor and on the manifest file. It still doesn't change when we try to sun it on the emulator. Please, help us. I hope you can provide a better and effective solution on this problem.

Comment: try uninstall all previous apks

Comment: thanks.. but how can i do that?

Comment: from emulator setting uninstall previous apk

Answer (score 0):

This instructions might help you to uninstall your application or reset an emulator. 
To fully reset a Android emulator:

Open the Android AVD manager ->
Start the emulator you want to reset->
Check the "Wipe user data" box->
Click on button

Or if you just want to remove one applications.

Start the emulator->
Open the Android settings app->
Select "Applications"->
Select "Manage Applications" ->Select the application and click"Uninstall"

Also you can do it via adb `adb uninstall <package name>`

Comment: thank you for the answer. but now we can't open a single file now after doing some renaming attempts.

Comment: clean - > invalidate cashes -> reimport and rebuild your poroject and then try to deploy it on device it might help